# Chrome and PHP 5.4 server

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4 and the "php artisan serve --port 3000" command to leverage PHP 5.4 cli server.  I go to localhost:3000/ in FireFox and I get "Hello World" which means everything is working right.  When I do the same in Chrome i get the error "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000"

I've tried the basic "php -S localhost:3000 -t public/" and that fails only in Chrome as well.  Any issues with chrome and localhost:[port] that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 2):

It'a a Chrome bug see [chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215)
You have to disable "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" in chrome flags: in address bar type  chrome://flags/

Answer (score 1):

Oh! Gods come to me!!

I've found my solution. Try to use ipv6 so you should check http://[::1]:3000 instead of http: //localhost:3000

I cant tell you why this works well , however it will work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me!

Im using localhost:80 but fails only in Chrome(firefox works well).

And via Apache Chrome show me correct page.

So PHP5.4 Cli Sever + chrome(maybe 26.0.1410.43:Mar 27 release) is bad pair...i think.